# access to the root folder for client side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new in the development of server-side applications. I have a collection in mongodb which stores names of files that store in the root directory `/uploads`. I have to download them on client side using the angular. But using the `ng-src` or simple `src` out of `ng-repeat` I get a 404 error.
Is there any way to get the client-side access to the directory with the files?

```
<div class="row jumbotron" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <img ng-src="../../../uploads/{{item.logo}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" ng-click="showModal($index)">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: architecture of app]

Also tried to provided file through `../` - 404 (Not Found)

```
<div>
    <img src="../../../uploads/38809344bac1a3a77c5d1e0493763849.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you provided will go up three folders and then will look for the uploads folder, as each `../` means: Go up one level (**relative path notation**). If this is not the case, please update the question with a sample of your folder structure. Relative paths start from the current folder in which your HTML file resides on the server.

Another point to keep in mind: If you're using **Linux**, The privileges of the `/uploads` folder must allow the application to access it.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X. I'm already tried to provide by ../../../ - also 404 error .

P.S. Update question

Comment: @Merge-pony Looks like you're trying to access a folder outside the application (project) folder, am I right?
If that's the case, you have multiple options:
1- Use absolute (full) path to the uploads folder (not recommended since the folder path will change if you move your project to another location/machine).
2- Move the uploads folder inside the project folder, so that you can access the files without access permission problems
3- Using Node.js? use its server-side JS to provide you with the image paths. It will surely have access to this folder.

Comment: may I choose  to call a friend to solve this quiz?) 
Well, 1 and 2 versions are not suitable. How can I provide images? Can you write an example please or link some?

Comment: Yes :D

I'm no expert in Node.JS and Mac is a myth for me, sorry.

I know  that NodeJS is written in JS. Why don't you create a script that constructs the image paths and passes them along in responses to Angular's $http service?

Comment: path to images are storing in mongodb. And then clint getting those paths with 404 error...

Comment: @Merge-pony: How do you generate your upload folder paths before storing them in MongoDB?

Comment: using upload through angular-file-upload and multer (for express 4.x), getting post to server and insert path to variable and write it to db when create collection.

P.S. Well, I didn't find solution of this problem, so I guess I need to change logic of storing files.

Comment: Move `upload` folder inside `img`. Configure `ng-file-upload` to upload there. Use it `ng-src="img/uploads"` (if your code is written in the index page. Sorry, it's all I can think of right now.

Comment: this is a very bad way to keep upload images on client side because there are will be a huge amount of images

Comment: Don't worry. They won't be on the client side. They will be inside your application folder in NodeJS. The role of `ng-src` is to tell the  browser where to find and download the image from.